# What is the best way to detect a mouseDown, drag and mouseUp event in JavaScript where nothing is actually dragged?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, mouseevent

What is the best way to detect a mouseDown, drag and mouseUp event in JavaScript where nothing is actually dragged?

I want to use drag inputs in a website where the user clicks and drags but nothing is actually dragged as far as the DOM goes.

When I click and drag in the browser sometimes the mouseUp is not detected.
Also sometimes if the user clicks on some content, the content is picked up and dragged in Firefox, though I wonder this might be a browser specific issue. I want to somehow stop this behaviour.

Also in Chrome I have noticed that I get a page like icon sometimes when dragging. Which I would also like to prevent. Development/Test OS is Ubuntu.

How best can I track drags with the mouse and also prevent these strange browser issues and have reliable mouseUp events as these seem to fail intermittently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );

function onMouseDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents browser to follow links or move images
    // code to execute on mouse click
}

document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );

function onMouseMove(e) {
    // code to execute on mouse mouse move
}

document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );

function onMouseUp(e) {
    // code to execute on mouse mouse up
}
```

This might prevent you from clicking links, you will have to add code to overcome this, such as:

```
$('a').click(function() {
   window.location = this.href;
}
```

This is code off the top of my head, should be close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks for this. It has cleared up all of my drag issues. I am still able to click on links though which is preferable.